# Steam requires execute permissions

Tags: permissions, steam, home-directory

I've got Steam installed on my Ubuntu 14.04. system, and it has worked so far. But now, when I start Steam, my installed games appear to be not installed, and when I click on 'Install', it says that I have no free space. When I am to create a new Steam library folder in my home folder, it says that "new steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions".

Here's the output of starting steam in the terminal:

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Pavilion-13-x360-PC:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (3117) : Assertion Failed: CApplicationManager::GetMountVolume: invalid index
Assert( Assertion Failed: CApplicationManager::GetMountVolume: invalid index ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp:3117

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
assert_20150729211458_7.dmp[3780]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20150729211458_7.dmp
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (3117) : Assertion Failed: CApplicationManager::GetMountVolume: invalid index
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (3268) : Assertion Failed: m_vecInstallBaseFolders.Count() > 0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Dongle firmware /home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/../controller_base/d0ggle.bin loaded, version 1435869091.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49,15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442,37 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
assert_20150729211458_7.dmp[3780]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
assert_20150729211458_7.dmp[3780]: error: HTTP response code said error
assert_20150729211458_7.dmp[3780]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20150729211458_7.dmp'', upload no: ''HTTP response code said error''
Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0, 1, 11, 77, 482, 6143, 6183, 7566, 11612, 11728, 11729, 45613, 46748, 47831, 50789
roaming config store loaded successfully - 1806 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (3117) : Assertion Failed: CApplicationManager::GetMountVolume: invalid index
Dongle firmware /home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/../controller_base/d0ggle.bin loaded, version 1435869091.
Dongle firmware /home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/../controller_base/d0ggle.bin loaded, version 1435869091.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
System startup time: 4,99 seconds
Generating new string page texture 72: 64x256, total string texture memory is 507,90 KB
Generating new string page texture 73: 128x256, total string texture memory is 638,98 KB
Generating new string page texture 74: 256x256, total string texture memory is 901,12 KB
Generating new string page texture 75: 32x256, total string texture memory is 933,89 KB
Generating new string page texture 76: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1,98 MB
Generating new string page texture 77: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2,11 MB
Generating new string page texture 78: 8x256, total string texture memory is 2,12 MB
Generating new string page texture 79: 512x256, total string texture memory is 2,65 MB
Generating new string page texture 80: 256x256, total string texture memory is 262,14 KB
Generating new string page texture 87: 256x256, total string texture memory is 2,91 MB
Generating new string page texture 88: 128x256, total string texture memory is 3,04 MB
Generating new string page texture 93: 2048x256, total string texture memory is 5,14 MB
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
```

Here is what mount gives

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Pavilion-13-x360-PC:~$ mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/home/stefan/.Private on /home/stefan type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=ad1391fcd7c8357f,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=37a8f0d041e8ebdb)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=stefan)
```

Does anyone have an idea what that could be?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. Oh! I see that you just asked 2 hours ago. Maybe this a problem related to an update that just came. Time will tell!

Comment: @skaz: After upgrading to the latest kernel version, it now works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upgrade to `linux-image` version 3.13.0-61 run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then `reboot` and it will work again